# How to install packages to docker's python?

Tags: python, django, docker

How to install packages to docker's python?

For example, I need `lmxl`. Inside django application in docker I run `pip install lxml` and terminal responses that requirement is already satisfied (because it's installed in OS X python 2.7 packages), but in fact it's not installed in docker's python packages.

So, how to apply `pip install something` to docker?

Comment: Are you using a `Dockerfile`?

Comment: @flowfree so you mean putting RUN pip install something into Dockerfile?

Comment: I want to know how you are running docker, do you create a custom `Dockerfile` or simply run the existing Python image

Comment: @flowfree creating a custom Dockerfile

Comment: Then yes, you can install it with `RUN pip install lxml` in your `Dockerfile`

Comment: @flowfree edited Dockefile, ran 'docker-compose up' and it still saying 'ImportError: No module named lxml'

Comment: I believe you should do `docker-compose build` then `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to update the requirements.txt file of your project.

```
# requirements.txt
# .. other requirements
lxml
```

add the lxml dependencies to your Dockerfile after (RUN apt-get update .....)

```
RUN apt-get install -y python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev
```

now build and run. Using either

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

or

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Comment: Since RUN decides whether to create a new layer based on the command string, does `RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip` create new layer or re-use an existing layer?

Answer (score 1):

You would use Docker's `docker-compose run --rm --service-ports web bash` command. That will bring you to the command line of the container. Once there, you can run `pip install lxml`. After installation, just type `exit`, and you will exit the container used to the `web` container and remove it.

Here's the article on Docker run for reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to install packages in docker but i prefer is to use docker file 
https://rominirani.com/docker-tutorial-series-writing-a-dockerfile-ce5746617cd#.q00am7bh3

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/docker-explained-using-dockerfiles-to-automate-building-of-images

check out these links it might help you.